# Get POVRay-source file from addon

Tags: export, add-on

I installed the POV-Ray-addon to use this renderer with blender which works quite fine for me. The problem is I want to comprehend the render with POV-Ray and would like to see the source code just like I would edit a .pov-file and render it straight with the command.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The [exporter's wiki page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/POV-Ray) contains all necessary information to get you started in several languages,

It is possible to edit the options of where and how to write the pov file, when "AUTO"(car icon) is unchecked in *render* tab's **INI Options** panel

If you uncheck *Delete file* option, you will be able to open the rendered pov file from the temporary folder, or the folder of your choice if any has been specified.

Some topics include [command line switches](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/POV-Ray#Command_line_switches) to pass parameters as you would through the command prompt when launching POV from a terminal or from ini files.